# Using import to "organize" routes folder for Express in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I recently started using ECMAScript (ES6) for my NodeJS Rest API which uses Express, and I've ran into a couple issues with the new keyword `import`

Before, I'd "organize" my routes folder doing so:

Let's call this file **devices_id.js**

```
export default (app) => {
    return app.get("/devices/:id", (req, res) => {
        res.send("OK");
    });
};
```

And on my main file I would do:

```
require("./routes")(app); // app is my Express instance
```

I have no idea how to do this with ES6, I've tried `import("./routes")` but it doesn't let me pass the **app** object

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a key [feature](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) in express here, `express.router`.
You'd have the app.js importing and attaching each file

```js
import route1 from './routes/route1'
import route2 from './routes/route2'

app.use('/route1', route1) // All routes in here starts with /route1
app.use('/test', route2) // All routes in here starts with /test
```

And then you have each router file setup like this

/routes/route1

```js
import express from 'express'

const router = express.Router()

// GET /route1/foo
router.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  res.send('OK')
})

export default router
```

Note that this code is not tested

---

EDIT

Unfortunately there's currently no way to dynamically import routes in ES6 express. However I've been using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-recursive-routes) library for that for years now which works great. It scans all folders and sub folders in the routes folder and adds the files to your express instance. It also uses the names of the files and folder as the name of the endpoint. So with a good folder structure it's awesome and very dynamic.

Comment: Hi, that's what I don't want, I don't want to be importing every file and then to manually .use it I want an automated way, I most likely left something out in the example I believe it to be the fs.readdir and all that, sorry!

Comment: I understand. Unfortunately there's currently no way to do that in es6 express. However i've been using a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-recursive-routes) for that for years now which works great. It scans all folders and sub folders in the routes folder and adds them to your express instance. It also uses the names of the files and folder as the name of the endpoint. So with a good folder structure it's awesome.

Comment: Well that fixes my problem, thanks for that awesome library!

Comment: I'll update my answer with this comment to make sure it's a complete answer for your case.

Comment: Just make sure to include the library link ;)